# Syntax error on token “else”

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please help, I want to make the button visible only if the checkbox is checked. But the token "else" gives me a syntax error. What do you think it could be? For a while I thought  it could be some bracket but I don't really know.

```
package com.example.holaamigos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_SALUDO = "com.example.holaamigos.SALUDO";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText txtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TxtNombre);
    final Button btnHola = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnHola);
    final CheckBox checkbox1 =(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                    boolean checked) {
                if (checked)

                    Toast.makeText(checkbox1.getContext(), "Activo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    btnHola.setVisibility(0);
                    btnHola.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySaludo.class);
                            String saludo = txtNombre.getText().toString();
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SALUDO, saludo);
                            startActivity(intent);

                else 

                    Toast.makeText(checkbox1.getContext(), "Inactivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });
}



});

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: That is the reason that always use `{}` for `If-else`. This is another example.

Comment: You've made a mistake because your formatting with respect to indentation is such a mess. If you put that right you might spot the error yourself. Don't be so sloppy.

Comment: Off topic but I would recommend using the constants for `visibility` `View.GONE`, `View.INVISIBLE`, `View.VISIBLE` instead of the `int`

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F for auto-format. Please use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it for

```
        boolean checked) {
            if (checked)
                {
                Toast.makeText(checkbox1.getContext(), "Activo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                btnHola.setVisibility(0);
                btnHola.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivitySaludo.class);
                        String saludo = txtNombre.getText().toString();
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SALUDO, saludo);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
            else 
            {

                Toast.makeText(checkbox1.getContext(), "Inactivo" Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you have multiple instructions in an if else statement, you should use `{}` i.e :

```
if (checked){    
    //your code goes here
}
else {
    //One instruction so you can leaves braces but it's better to put them
    Toast.makeText(checkbox1.getContext(), "Inactivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

A good practice is too always englobe your instructions in `{}` even if you have only one.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) :

> In addition, the opening and closing braces are optional, provided
>   that the "then" clause contains only one statement
>
> Deciding when to omit the braces is a matter of personal taste.
>   Omitting them can make the code more brittle. If a second statement is
>   later added to the "then" clause, a common mistake would be forgetting
>   to add the newly required braces. **The compiler cannot catch this sort
>   of error; you'll just get the wrong results**.

Comment: I agree with always using "{}" if for no other reason than it will help reduce this mistake later on if you decide to add more lines it also helps the readability, IMHO